# zero-padding time, combining date/time and subtracting hours

Tags: python, datetime

I have an csv file, this is a sample of columns

[image]

My overall goal is to read the file and subtract 5 hours from the time points.
I first read the file:

```
data= pandas.read_csv(file)
```

Then I want to combine date and time object into one datetime object using datetime.combine, however I want to add zero padding before the day and time. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Use [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explain what you want.

Comment: what does it mean to "add zero padding before the day and time" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do what you need?

```py
import pandas as pd 

input_data = pd.read_csv('Input_data.csv', header=None, names=('Date', 'Time'))
datetime_series = pd.to_datetime(input_data['Date'] + ' ' + input_data['Time'])
past_series = datetime_series + pd.Timedelta("-5 hours")
print("Original time")
print(datetime_series)
print("\n\n5 hours before")
print(past_series)
```